# My files are created with the wrong owner

Tags: linux, arch-linux, permissions, chown

In my case when I create a file or folder as user ludow the owner of the file or folder is root

exemple

```bash
❯ whoami
ludow
```

```bash
❯ touch test

❯ ls -al | grep test
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root      0 30 oct.  21:02 test
```

chown not working

```bash
❯ chown -v ludow:ludow test
membership of 'test' changed from root:root to ludow:ludow
```

the owner doesn't change

```bash
❯ ls -al | grep test
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root      0 30 oct.  21:02 test
```

all my files are owned by root, even those that shouldn't be

here is some information about my environment

```
❯ neofetch
                   '                      ludow@Spiron
                  'o'                     ------------
                 'ooo'                    OS: Artix Linux x86_64
                'ooxoo'                   Host: Inspiron 15 5510
               'ooxxxoo'                  Kernel: 6.0.5-x64v1-xanmod1
              'oookkxxoo'                 Uptime: 54 mins
             'oiioxkkxxoo'                Packages: 1252 (pacman), 5 (flatpak)
            ':;:iiiioxxxoo'               Shell: zsh 5.9
               `'.;::ioxxoo'              Resolution: 1920x1080, 1920x1080
          '-.      `':;jiooo'             DE: Plasma 5.26.2
         'oooio-..     `'i:io'            WM: KWin
        'ooooxxxxoio:,.   `'-;'           Theme: Artix-dark [Plasma], Artix-dark [GTK2/3]
       'ooooxxxxxkkxoooIi:-.  `'          Icons: [Plasma], Colloid-nord-dark [GTK2/3]
      'ooooxxxxxkkkkxoiiiiiji'            Terminal: alacritty
     'ooooxxxxxkxxoiiii:'`     .i'        CPU: 11th Gen Intel i5-11320H (8) @ 4.500GHz
    'ooooxxxxxoi:::'`       .;ioxo'       GPU: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
   'ooooxooi::'`         .:iiixkxxo'      Memory: 3500MiB / 7696MiB
  'ooooi:'`                `'';ioxxo'
 'i:'`                          '':io'
'`                                   `'
```

what would be a solution to restore the default behavior, without reinstalling os?

---

/etc/fstab

```
# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass> 
UUID=5895-EEC1                            /boot/efi      vfat    umask=0077 0 2 
UUID=04cddafd-0517-4528-a181-d4592f483992 /              xfs     defaults,noatime 0 1 
UUID=9cfe2ed5-6cc5-4a67-8bf8-bad85c9a3f3d swap           swap    defaults,noatime 0 0 
UUID=05F56DAC5B0B310A                     /home          ntfs    defaults,noatime 0 2 
tmpfs                                     /tmp           tmpfs   defaults,noatime,mode=1777
```

Comment: gut feeling is that this is something to do with the filesystem itself.
Maybe look at `/etc/fstab` to see what file system type is mounted and if there are any special options.

Comment: thank you for your reply,
my fsat file looks normal
  





```shell
# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=5895-EEC1                            /boot/efi      vfat    umask=0077 0 2
UUID=04cddafd-0517-4528-a181-d4592f483992 /              xfs     defaults,noatime 0 1
UUID=9cfe2ed5-6cc5-4a67-8bf8-bad85c9a3f3d swap           swap    defaults,noatime 0 0
UUID=05F56DAC5B0B310A                     /home          ntfs    defaults,noatime 0 2
tmpfs                                     /tmp           tmpfs   defaults,noatime,mode=1777
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your home directory is an NTFS partition (from Microsoft Windows).  NTFS has a very different permissions model to Linux and so users cannot be directly mapped into Linux out of the box.

The behaviour you're seeing is the default behaviour where all files in the partition are automatically interpreted as being owned by `root`.

I believe there is now a way to map NTFS users into Linux users, you may need to spend some time on Google figuring out how.  There's some reference to it here: https://man.archlinux.org/man/extra/ntfs-3g/ntfsusermap.8.en

---

As a general rule, it's not a great idea to have your Windows home directory be exactly the same as your Linux home directory.  Applications will try to store files on the root of the home directory with configuration and caches etc.  If you happen to install the same app on both OS, you may find that the cache or config differ enough to confuse the app in one OS or the other.

Generally it's better to have a sub directory (perhaps even `~/Documents`) be shared, but the root `~` be separate.